# Способы объявления объекта структуры

Tags: c++

Есть структура:

```
struct Node {int value;};
```

Есть ли разница в этих строчках?:

```
Node A;
struct Node A;
```

Comment: В C++ разницы нет; в C первая строчка просто не сработает (если, конечно, нет еще какого-то определения `Node`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В С++ префикс `struct` является опциональным, но он все равно может понадобиться, если имя класса в текущей области видимости переиспользовано (чего следует избегать):

```
struct Node {int value;};
int Node;
Node a; // error
struct Node b; // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Слово `struct` при объявлении объекта необходимо только в C. В C++ со структурами можно работать в точности так же, как с классами, не имеющими методов и содержащими только `public` свойства.